# *ngFor depending on 2 arrays matching values

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have some issues understanding how I can do an ***ngFor** loop which depend on the values I have in 2 different arrays, example :

Array : **label_name**

[image]

Array : **total_by_level**

[image]

I'm doing an ngFor and I want the ngFor to render lines that have a value inside those 2 arrays, here, my ngFor should render : **Network  Main: 1537.82, Drops Drop Aluminium : 21752.15  and Misc VANNE :  19541** with their respecting values

I've tried with foreach and filter but none of solutions I've found on the net fitted my issue.

If anyone have an idea of where I need to go/what I need to do I would appreciate it.

Thank's in advance

**CODE SAMPLE :**

HTML :

```
<div class="container dpf wid">
  <form [formGroup]="cartForm">
        <div *ngFor="let levels of total_by_level"
             style="display: contents">
          <div *ngFor="let level_names of label_name">
          <a class="flex1 bold pointer" >TOTAL {{level_names}} {{levels[2][3]}}</a>
        </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

component.ts :

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private service: QuotationMenuService) { }

  cartForm: FormGroup;
  quotArray: any;
  quotDetails: any;
  cartDetails: any;
  labels: any;
  label_name: any;
  total_by_level: any;
  array: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.requiredFields();
    this.service.getStructure().subscribe(res => {
      this.labels = res.parts;
      this.label_name = Array(res.labels_levels);
      console.log(this.label_name);
    });
    this.initQuot();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.initQuot();
  }

  initQuot(){
    this.service.checkExistQuot().subscribe(res => {
      this.quotArray = res;
      this.quotDetails = res.quotation.quotationdetail;
      this.cartDetails = Array(res.cart);
      console.log(this.quotDetails);
      console.log(this.cartDetails);
      this.total_by_level = Array(res.cart.total_by_level);
      console.log(this.total_by_level);
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.cartForm.controls;
  }

  requiredFields(){
    this.cartForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {

      }
    )
  }
```

Here's what it actually look like for the moment on my page :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the input arrays need to be reformatted. This is certainly a solution for a problem that could be avoided in the first place.

That said, you could try the following loop

Controller

```js
for (const levelKey in this.total_by_level[0]) {
  if (this.total_by_level[0].hasOwnProperty(levelKey)) {   // <-- add check here to avoid error
    const key = this.label_name[0][levelKey] + ' ' + this.label_name[0][Object.keys(this.total_by_level[0][levelKey])[0]];
    const value = this.total_by_level[0][levelKey][Object.keys(this.total_by_level[0][levelKey])[0]];
    this.output_object[key] = value;
  }
}
```

where `output_object = Object.create(null)`.

And display it in the template

```html
<div *ngFor="let output of output_object | keyvalue">
  {{ output.key }}: {{ output.value }}
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkgjr5)

Comment: Hello ! First of all, thank's for the great answer, I'm getting "Possible iteration over unexpected (custom / inherited) members, probably missing hasOwnProperty check" cause of 'this.total_by_level[0]' do you know if I should edit the array to already loop on the values inside [0] ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it should only be a warning and the code should run. Nevertheless, you could also include the check it requires in the loop. I've updated the answer and Stackblitz. Please check my code.

Comment: Thank you, the array can't loop in the [0] part of this.total_by_level[0], I'm getting : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, can't I only loop into the datas instead of my Array creating the [0] level ?

Comment: I worked with the object array that you posted in the screenshots. May be the actual object is different. Should be a simple fix. Console log the objects, check the structure and remove the `[0]` part from the code above if it isn't an array. The basic implementation remains the same.

Comment: Alright ! Thank's for your help ! I'll mark it as the answer since the problem now comes from my datas